# Object variables comparison in Javascript's HTMLCollection

Tags: javascript, dom

```
var elem1, elem2;

// document.forms is an HTMLCollection

elem1 = document.forms[0];
elem2 = document.forms.item(0);

alert(elem1 === elem2); // shows: "true"

elem1 = document.forms["myForm"];
elem2 = document.forms.namedItem("myForm");

alert(elem1 === elem2); // shows: "true"
```

Src: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection

In the above code variables `elem1` and `elem2` both hold same object, i.e. a DOM node

I would like to know, In the statement `elem1 === elem2` what is actually being compared 
so that it evaluates to a `TRUE` expression. Is it `nodeType`, `nodeValue` or `nodeName` ?

Comment: See also this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1068834/object-comparison-in-javascript

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No property is actually compared. `elem1` and `elem2` are *references* to objects, and it happens that both variables point to the same object.

You could have used `==` too, in this case. `===` additionally checks for the *type* of the argument.

Comment: Does that applies to the following var myCar= new car(); or var x=document.getElementById("para"); I mean myCar and x are references to objects ?

Comment: @dkjain: All Javascript variables are references to objects (except primitive values)

Answer (score 4):

None of the above.

The `===` operator checks for *reference* equality.
It will only ever return true if both expressions refer to the same object.